# Is it possible Firebase Remote Config to be queried from backend service REST?

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, firebase-ab-testing

I have an idea to make my apps to be Backend Driven and for this reason I want to query Firebase Remote Config for some values which has some condition properties when they should be applied (for example: parameter show_banner should be applied only for Country: Portugal) and I want to have the possibility to use A/B testing for such scenarios.

In other words I want my backend microservice to make requests to Firebase Remote COnfig (with A/B testing feature) on behalf of mobile applications (I can have information about the version, country, mobile id etc.. in the backend). Is there any REST APIs that can help me achieving this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [REST API for Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/remote-config/rest) only allows managing the template, so the equivalent of the operations you can perform in the Firebase console.

There is no public REST (or other server) API to get a set of remote config values for a specific device. That operation is only possible through the client-side SDKs.

Comment: Does this mean that acessing remote config values is impossible to do from a C# WPF app, for instance? Any idea whether a C# SDK will be available any time in the future?